# SSIS package with ODBC SSL target connection fails, while no SSL execution is successful

Tags: sql-server, ssl, ssis, odbc, hana

I have an issue with an SSL ODBC connection from SSIS Package, while the package is executed by SQL Agent.

I am using a technical user (ActiveDirectory account) used to execute (run as) a step in a SQL Agent job that calls the package.
The user has a proxy credential and all required privileges on SQL server to execute the job and all dependent resources from SQL server, as while the DSN, used by SSIS ODBC connection is configured without SSL it works as flawless.

When the "Connect using SSL" property is set, I am getting a generic error message: 
:Error: Failed to acquire connection "". Connection may not be configured correctly or you may not have the right permissions on this connection.

I have noticed, by accident while debugging, that if I have any application running or a session established for the technical user to the server, the load with SSL configuration ends successfully. When the session is terminated/closed the error comes back.

Please advise, what has to be reconfigured to make it work with SSL!

Environment:
SQL Server 2016 (v: 13.0.4001.0)
SQL Agent runs as: NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT
SAP Hana is a target DB
SQL Server runs on Windows Server 2016